# How to open different tables in MS Acess using combobox in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

This code was given by my lecturer and this code is meant to retrieve data from ms access. I tried to adjust it instead of just opening one table, i can select a table from ms access by using combobox that is populated with tables name. but i got error "Syntax error in FROM clause".

This is the code:

```
             //to clear existing  data in the view
            dataGridView.Rows.Clear();
            //SQL retrieve in DB
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM" + comboBoxcatagory.Text;
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);

            //open connection to DB
            con.Open();
            adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                //create function populate
                populate(row[0].ToString(), row[1].ToString(), row[2].ToString());
            }

            //close DB connection 
            con.Close();
            //clear the data row
            dt.Rows.Clear();
            //Bind to load in text box
            dataGridView.SelectionChanged += dataGridView_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

Comment: While this is only an exercise, don't ever do this in production code. This is a prime example of a possible SQL injection. Use prepared statements.

Comment: @nkr only issue is most doesnt allow table names as parameters

Comment: @BugFinder True in this case but one should either prepare enough statements or make it impossible to freely type any string in untrusted environments. Better to learn the basics now than to break the habits later.

Comment: @nkr I dont disagree.

Comment: as a side note, take the habit to wrap your connection (and every IDisposable object) in a `using` statement: thill will ensure connection will be closed (i.e. released to the connection pool) at the end of the method. The same apply also to your OleDbCommand and OleDbDataAdapter

Answer (score 2):

You need a space after "FROM" ..

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM" + comboBoxcatagory.Text;
```

your code would produce say "SELECT * FROMmytable"

You need

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM " + comboBoxcatagory.Text;
```

Comment: i did this but still got the same error. thanks for helping tho

Comment: OK so what is the generated SQL?  what is the value of sql after generating it?

Comment: that was going to be my next comment, that and/or is the table name a reserved word

Answer (score 1):

Because table name stick to `From`, You need space after `From` Do something like:

```
 string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", comboBoxcatagory.Text.Trim());
```

or in C# 6:

```
var name= comboBoxcatagory.Text.Trim();
string sql =  $"SELECT * FROM {name}";
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make space after from in your SQL query it should like

```
 string sql = "SELECT * FROM " + comboBoxcatagory.Text.trim();
```